# how to create a folder per date and put files inside?

Tags: python

I am crating a folder per date, then I create a set of files under  that folder. I am using this function for that:

```
path_stats= pathlib.Path('/home/dataset/Signal_Synchronization_Traces/' + str(date.today()) + '_Results/Statistical_Test_Results').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
print(path_stats)

for i in range(10):
    file = open(str(path_stats)+'/File'+ str(i) + '.txt','wb')
    file.write('hello')
    print('done')
    file.close
```

However, this function results an error:

```
    file = open(str(path_stats)+'/File'+ str(i) + '.txt','wb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'None/File0.txt'
None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer:

```
path_stats = pathlib.Path('/tmp/home/dataset/Signal_Synchronization_Traces/' + str(date.today()) + '_Results/Statistical_Test_Results')
path_stats.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

#### Long answer:

path_stats did not contains directory string

```
from datetime import date
import pathlib

path_stats = pathlib.Path('/tmp/home/dataset/Signal_Synchronization_Traces/' + str(date.today()) + '_Results/Statistical_Test_Results').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
print(path_stats)
```

variable is:

```
None
```

you need to store variable before and run method mkdir on it

```
from datetime import date
import pathlib

path_stats = pathlib.Path('/tmp/home/dataset/Signal_Synchronization_Traces/' + str(date.today()) + '_Results/Statistical_Test_Results')
path_stats.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
print(path_stats)
```

then variable contains path:

```
/tmp/home/dataset/Signal_Synchronization_Traces/2019-01-15_Results/Statistical_Test_Results
```

then you will be able to run your code

```
for i in range(10):
    file = open(str(path_stats) + '/File' + str(i) + '.txt', 'wb')
    file.write(b'hello')
    print(str(path_stats) + '/File' + str(i) + '.txt')
    print('done')
    file.close()
```

produce:

```
/tmp/home/dataset/Signal_Synchronization_Traces/2019-01-15_Results/Statistical_Test_Results/File0.txt
done
/tmp/home/dataset/Signal_Synchronization_Traces/2019-01-15_Results/Statistical_Test_Results/File1.txt
done
(...)
```

Caution: if you use binary file - then you need to save binary data.

```
file = open(str(path_stats) + '/File' + str(i) + '.txt', 'wb')
file.write(b'hello')
```

alternative:

```
file = open(str(path_stats) + '/File' + str(i) + '.txt', 'w')
file.write('hello')
```

Comment: Thank you very much really for your help and explanation. But I have this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mkdir'

Comment: Have you removed `.mkdir(...)` at the end of this `path_stats = pathlib.Path(...)` line?

Comment: it was my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Create the folder structure before trying to open the file:

```
import os
for i in range(10):
    filename = str(path_stats)+'/File'+ str(i) + '.txt'
    # Create folder structure
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)
    file = open(filename,'wb')
    file.write('hello')
    print('done')
    file.close
```

Note that you won't be able to write the string 'hello', as you opened the file in binary mode.

Comment: Thank you but it gives me ythe same error. the problem is with creating the folder since as output error it gives me Non/File0

Answer (score 2):

`path_stats` is `None`, hence `str(path_stats)+'/File'+ str(i) + '.txt'` results with 'None/File0.txt' which is not a directory.

The reason is that `pathlib.mkdir` has no return value. Change your code to:

```
...
path_stats = pathlib.Path('/home/dataset/Signal_Synchronization_Traces/' + str(date.today()) + '_Results/Statistical_Test_Results')
path_stats.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
print(path_stats)
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much really for your help and explanation. But I have this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mkdir'

Comment: That's because path_stats is None (note that's why I removed the call to mkdir from the first line). Since you accepted an answer I guess you figured it out by now :)